# example of a scheme where connected components aren't open

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

In general topology connected components are open if there are finitely many of them, but otherwise may not be. For example, the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ are the singletons, which are closed but not open.

What are some interesting examples of schemes where connected components aren't open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about *interesting*, but there are examples. Let $A = \mathbb{F}_2^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. the cartesian product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$ and let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$. I claim $X$ is the ultrafilter space $\beta \mathbb{N}$, also known as the Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$.

By construction, $A$ is a boolean ring, corresponding to the boolean algebra $\mathscr{P} (\mathbb{N})$, so maximal ideals of $A$ are the same as ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, since quotients of boolean rings are boolean rings, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $A / \mathfrak{p}$ is a boolean integral domain – but the only such thing is $\mathbb{F}_2$, so $\mathfrak{p}$ is also a maximal ideal.

Thus, there is a canonical bijection between the points of $X$ and the set of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. It is not hard to see that the Zariski topology on $X$ corresponds to the Stone topology on $\beta \mathbb{N}$, so we have a homeomorphism. But the latter is known to be totally disconnected and not discrete, so $X$ is a scheme whose connected components are not open.

Comment: Okay there are a lot of words here that I'm not familiar with (and are resistant to wikipedia-ing), so before I dive deeper, can I just check that here by ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, you mean a maximal filter on the totally ordered poset $\mathbb{N}$? (ie, the complement of a finite set?) Presumably given any such cofinite set, the corresponding prime ideal of $A$ is the kernel of the homomorphism to $\mathbb{F}_2$ sending the $i$th coordinate to 1 iff it's not in the ultrafilter?

Comment: No, I mean an ultrafilter _on_ $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. a maximal filter _of_ the poset $\mathscr{P} (\mathbb{N})$. To be completely precise, ultrafilters are the _complements_ of maximal ideals in the boolean ring $\mathbb{F}_2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Isn't your $A$ the (projective) limit of the rings $\mathbb{F}_2$ over the "discrete" category whose objects are natural numbers and morphisms are all identities?

Then, shouldn't Spec, being a contravariant equivalence of categories, commute with the limit, so that Spec $A$ should be the colimit of the Spec $\mathbb{F}_2$'s over the same "discrete" category, which must be a disjoint union?

I understand your argument and I agree that Spec $A$ is not the disjoint union of points, but I don't understand how this is compatible with what I said above.

Comment: The inclusion of affine schemes into all schemes only preserves finite coproducts.

Comment: do you have a reference for that statement by any chance?

Comment: No, but your observation proves it. More generally, observe that the coproduct of infinitely many non-empty schemes is _never_ quasicompact, yet every affine scheme is quasicompact.

Comment: that's a good point. Thanks!

Comment: Totally connected and non-discrete does not imply that no connected component is open since there may be isolated points that are themselves open components. The complement of all open components is the closed subscheme $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}\Spec A/J$ where $J$ is the ideal of finite sets supported sequences that has no open connected components. 

More generally, for any field $k$ and indexing set $I$, $\Spec k^I$ is the ultrafilter space $\beta I$. When $I$ is infinite, $\Spec k^I/J$, where $J$ is the ideal of finitely supported families, has no open connected components.