# Determinant of locally free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In $\textit{Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves}$, on page $237$, he defines the determinant $\operatorname{det} \mathscr{F}$ of a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$ by setting $(\operatorname{det} \mathscr{F})|_{X_i}:=\bigwedge^{r_i}(\mathscr{F}|_{X_i})$, where the $X_i$'s are the connected components of the scheme $X$ and $r_i$ denotes the rank of $\mathscr{F}$ on $X_i$.

How does one make sense of this definition? The $X_i$'s aren't even open in $X$ in general, so a glueing approach does not work. Actually there wouldn't be anything to check in this case since $X$ is the disjoint union of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: Connected components are open and closed.

Comment: @Mohan They are closed, but not necessarily open, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1155719/363120).

Comment: Liu works with Noetherian schemes in this context and then they are.

Comment: @Mohan Oh ok, I didn't see that, thanks. Could you please tell me where he writes this?

Comment: In fact the Noetherian hypothesis is not necessary for this case. Let $U_r$ be the set of points where your locally free sheaf has rank $r$. Then, it is clear that $U_r$ is open. Since $U_r\cap U_s=\emptyset$ if $r\neq s$, it follows that $U_r$ is also closed. Then, you can define the determinant to be the $r^{\mathrm{th}}$ exterior on $U_r$ and you are done. Each connected component of $X$ is contained in one of the $U_r$s.

Comment: @Mohan Fair enough. You can post this as an answer if you like.